# Удаление данных из БД по отправленному запросу из ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Имеется код получение данных из json файла, и заполнения таблицы данными где напротив каждой строки имеется кнопка удаления, id которой получаю и пытаюсь этот id отправить пост запросом на сервер, дабы тот в свою очередь удалил запись из json файла.

```
$.getJSON('table_push.json', function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('#users').append('<tr id=' + data[i].id + '><td>' + data[i].id +
                            '</td><td>' + data[i].firstName +
                            '</td><td>' + data[i].secondName +
                            '</td><td>' + data[i].email +
                            '</td><td><button data-id=' + data[i].id + ' class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>');
                    }
                    $(".btn-danger").bind('click', function () {
                        var line = $(this).data('id'); // тут id получаю, уже проверял его значение в консоли, всё верно
                        $('#' + line).remove(); //тут прото скрываю строку в таблицу
                        remove = 'remove='+line; //ну это переменная с id тоже выводится в alert правильное значение
                        $.ajax({ // вот тут я отправляю id на сервер
                            url: "core.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "text",
                            data: remove
                        });
                    });
        });
```

Снизу код php обработчика:

```
$idToDelete = filter_var($_POST["remove"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); //Удаляет все символы, кроме цифр и знаков плюса и минуса
$delete = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id`=".$idToDelete); // тут уже обращение к БД и удаление данных по полученному id
$goJson = 'writeJson';
$goJson();//вызываем функцию записи в json файл
```

Так вот, firebug показывает выполнение POST запроса как только нажму на кнопку удалить какую нибудь из строк, и значение которое отправляется то есть номер id. Но удаление из БД не происходит.  У меня есть предположение, что внутри функции $.getJSON не может содержаться ajax запрос на сервер, но запрос то проходит, к тому же за пределами этой функции я уже не могу получить значение переменной дабы выполнить за ее пределами ajax запрос. Сервер тоже по идеи должен принимать значения, ибо добавление данных в БД то происходит но удаление нет.

Comment: Вы всегда можете проверить выполнился Ваш запрос или нет - `if(!$delete){echo mysqli_error($CONNECT);}`

Comment: ошибка в запросе. 1) не хватает обратной кавычки в `WHERE` для `id`; 2) по-хорошему значения нужно обрамлять в кавычки, т.е. запрос должен быть *"DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `id`='$idToDelete'"*, где `test` и `id` должны быть в обратных кавычках.

Comment: На будущее проверяйте sql запросы перед добавлением в код например через phpmyadmin или через консольный mysql клиент.

Comment: @fens это не обязательно(см. первый комментарий).

Comment: @Alex да не обязательно но ответная реакция там быстрее. И как бонус новая версия pma имеет поддержку автодополнения.

Comment: @Alex Честно сказать, запросы на удаление в пхп писал по разному, и проверял их в самом phpmyadmin. По этому мне и кажется, что проблема всё таки на стороне клиента